# Porting C++ bitwise operations to Scala bitwise operations

Tags: c++, scala, bitwise-operators

I have a legacy C++ code which involves lots of bitwise oeprations. I have to port all that stuff to Scala. Is here some easy way like some library

Edit:
C++ code is as:

```
static uint64_t const C_MASK = 0x3FF;
static uint64_t const C_OFFSET = 46;
static uint64_t const G_MASK = 0x3FF;
static uint64_t const G_OFFSET = 46;
static uint64_t const W_MASK = 0x1FF;
static uint64_t const W_OFFSET = 16;
static uint64_t const H_OFFSET = 25;
static uint64_t const S_MASK = 0xF;
static uint64_t const S_OFFSET = 10;

result |= ((c & C_MASK) << C_OFFSET)
        | ((g & G_MASK) << G_OFFSET)
        | ((h & W_MASK) << H_OFFSET)
        | ((w & W_MASK) << W_OFFSET)
        | ((s & S_MASK) << S_OFFSET);
```

c,g,h,w,s are inputs.

I ported code to Scala as(with constants same as in C++ code):

```
def encode(c: Long = 0, g: Long = 0, w: Double = 0,
                      h: Double = 0, s: Int = 3) = {
      val result = ((c & C_MASK) << C_OFFSET)
            | ((g & G_MASK) << G_OFFSET)
            | ((h & W_MASK) << H_OFFSET)
            | ((w & W_MASK) << W_OFFSET)
            | ((s & S_MASK) << S_OFFSET);
}
```

Now to test this code, I have test code as:

```
val result = encode(c=10, g=20, w=10, h=15, s=3)
val c = (result >>> C_OFFSET) & C_MASK
val g = (result >>> G_OFFSET) & G_MASK
val w = (result >>> W_OFFSET) & W_MASK
val h = (result >>  H_OFFSET) & W_MASK
val s = (result >>  S_OFFSET) & S_MASK
```

The values I got are as:

> c=0, g=768, w=0,h=0,s=3

Except s, all others are different from what I passed to the function.

I am not sure what mistake I am making here.

Comment: Know nothing about scala, but there should be one to one mapping between bitwise operations

Comment: The basic bit operators are the same, `&`, `|`, and `^`. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is too general to answer, so can you give a more specific example of an operator that you have in `C++` that doesn't directly translate to Scala?

Comment: Is it bitshifts that you are having problems with? You'd probably want to use the unsigned bitshift operators `<<<` and `>>>` when translating a C++ program to Scala (if Scala works like Java).

Comment: It'd help if you provide a (small) example of some C++ code and how you're trying to port it to Scala

Comment: Include how far you've come with the translation too. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: have a look at this library: http://scodec.org/guide/scodec-bits.html

Comment: I see no issues from the posted code. A Scala `Long` is signed, not unsigned, but that shouldn't make any difference as none of the mask-with-offset values will touch the sign bit, and I rather doubt it would matter much if it did.

Comment: I have added further details to the question.

Comment: The posted code doesn't compile so it can't have produced the results you report. After making enough mods to get it to compile I tested it and got the expected results. (Expected given that the C and G offsets are the same.)